# Inconsistency in definition of antinodes

Tags: waves, terminology, distance, displacement

**Definition of antinode according to google**: the position of maximum displacement in a standing wave system

And displacement is a vector, so therefore, the crests would be the maximum while the troughs are the minimums.

From this, we can draw the conclusion that crests are antinodes while troughs can't be, as they're negative values.
*However*, the following graph shows otherwise:

[image: Diagram of a standing wave with antinodes labelled]

Something seems to be wrong here. If both crests and troughs are antinodes, then shouldn't the definition for antinodes be 'the position of maximum DISTANCE', where minimums and maximums have the same magnitudes?

Comment: -1. Nitpicking. Are you claiming that 'google' has made a mistake? 'Google' does not teach physics. Which website exactly? Please provide a reference. I think you understand the concept very well but you are just nitpicking over the words used.

Comment: @sammygerbil It's also the definition according to the physicsclassroom.com and my textbooks. This is something that I genuinely don't understand, which is why I'm on this forum.

Comment: replace "displacement" with "absolute displacement" and the problem goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the definition in terms of displacement because half a period later the graph looks like this.

[image]

So perhaps it would be better to have it as

- the position *where* maximum displacement *occurs* in a standing wave
  system

You could also use the terms "maximum amplitude" or "maximum magnitude of the displacement".

Comment: Yeah that puts a different view on it for me. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not sure whether these are strict definitions, the term *distance* is normally used as a scalar and *displacement* as a vector, so Wikipedia should be using the word *distance* rather than *displacement*.

Answer (score 0):

It is the position of maximum displacement in **either direction** in a standing wave system.

Various diagrams and sources on net proves it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).